# Change image opacity when select an option from a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I make when I select the option that has value 1(Mastercard) the image with id Master change the opacity to 1? And put it in a function that works for both 4 values, each on with his own id? The default image I want it to be 0.3 and when selected one of the option the image has the opacity 1.

```css
.itemForm2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.escolhaCartao {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 218px!important;
  gap: 10px;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .escolhaCartao {
    width: 258px!important;
    height: 34.32px;
    gap: 5px;
  }
  .lineFormCartao {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: inherit;
    gap: 16px;
  }
  .escolhaCartao img {
    opacity: .3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lineForm lineFormCartao">
  <div class="itemForm">
    <select id="OpcoesCartao" name="OpcoesCartao">
      <option value="1">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="2">Visa</option>
      <option value="3">Elo</option>
      <option value="4">Amex</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="itemForm2 escolhaCartao">
    <img id="master" src="images/master.png" alt="Logo cartão Mastercard">
    <img id="visa" src="images/visa.png" alt="Logo cartão Visa">
    <img id="elo" src="images/elo.png" alt="Logo cartão Elo">
    <img id="amex" src="images/amex.png" alt="Logo cartão Amex">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript to add an event listener to the dropdown and update the styles accordingly in case you want it work with Firefox browsers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. This works in most browsers. Firefox should support it soon (https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

```css
.itemForm2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.escolhaCartao {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 218px!important;
    gap: 10px;
}

.lineForm:has( option[value="1"]:checked ) #master {
  opacity: 1;
}
.lineForm:has( option[value="2"]:checked ) #visa {
  opacity: 1;
}
.lineForm:has( option[value="3"]:checked ) #elo {
  opacity: 1;
}
.lineForm:has( option[value="4"]:checked ) #amex {
  opacity: 1;
}


    .escolhaCartao {
        width: 258px!important;
        height: 34.32px;
        gap: 5px;
    }

    .lineFormCartao {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: inherit;
        gap: 16px;
    }
    .escolhaCartao img {
        opacity: .3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="lineForm lineFormCartao">
        <div class="itemForm">
             <select id="OpcoesCartao" name="OpcoesCartao">
                 <option value="1">Mastercard</option>
                 <option value="2">Visa</option>
                 <option value="3">Elo</option>
                 <option value="4">Amex</option>
             </select>
        </div>
        <div class="itemForm2 escolhaCartao">
            <img id="master" src="images/master.png" alt="Logo cartão Mastercard">
            <img id="visa" src="images/visa.png" alt="Logo cartão Visa">
            <img id="elo" src="images/elo.png" alt="Logo cartão Elo">
            <img id="amex" src="images/amex.png" alt="Logo cartão Amex">
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just CSS with has

```css
.escolhaCartao img {
 opacity: .2;
}

.itemForm:has(option[value="1"]:checked) + .itemForm2 > #master,
.itemForm:has(option[value="2"]:checked) + .itemForm2 > #visa,
.itemForm:has(option[value="3"]:checked) + .itemForm2 > #elo,
.itemForm:has(option[value="4"]:checked) + .itemForm2 > #amex
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineForm lineFormCartao">
  <div class="itemForm">
    <select id="OpcoesCartao" name="OpcoesCartao">
      <option value="1">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="2">Visa</option>
      <option value="3">Elo</option>
      <option value="4">Amex</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="itemForm2 escolhaCartao">
    <img id="master" src="images/master.png" alt="Logo cartão Mastercard">
    <img id="visa" src="images/visa.png" alt="Logo cartão Visa">
    <img id="elo" src="images/elo.png" alt="Logo cartão Elo">
    <img id="amex" src="images/amex.png" alt="Logo cartão Amex">
  </div>
</div>
```

with JavaScript

```js
var sel = document.querySelector("#OpcoesCartao");
const imgs =  document.querySelectorAll(".escolhaCartao img");

sel.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  const val = this.value;
  const selected = document.querySelector(".escolhaCartao img.selected");
  if (selected) {
    selected.classList.remove('selected');
  }
  imgs[+val - 1].classList.add('selected');
});

sel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```css
.escolhaCartao img {
 opacity: .2;
}

.escolhaCartao img.selected
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineForm lineFormCartao">
  <div class="itemForm">
    <select id="OpcoesCartao" name="OpcoesCartao">
      <option value="1">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="2">Visa</option>
      <option value="3">Elo</option>
      <option value="4">Amex</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="itemForm2 escolhaCartao">
    <img id="master" src="images/master.png" alt="Logo cartão Mastercard">
    <img id="visa" src="images/visa.png" alt="Logo cartão Visa">
    <img id="elo" src="images/elo.png" alt="Logo cartão Elo">
    <img id="amex" src="images/amex.png" alt="Logo cartão Amex">
  </div>
</div>
```